# How to get duration of active signal in bigquery?

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, duration

I have a bigquery table with various signals and a utc timestamp. I want to have as a query result the operating hours where the value of the column "Sensor" is greater than 1.

My idea was to get in some way min und max of the timestamp where Sensor > 1 and subtract min(timestamp) from max(timestamp) and aggregate it for where Sensor > 1 in a new column as operating hours.

```
timestamp,Sensor
2020-05-13 08:46:29 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:28 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:27 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:26 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:25 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:24 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:23 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:46:22 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:46:21 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:46:20 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:45:58 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:57 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:56 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:55 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:54 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:53 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:52 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:51 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:50 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:49 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:48 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:47 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:46 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:45 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:44 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:43 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:42 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:41 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:40 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:39 UTC,0.6486074
2020-05-13 08:45:38 UTC,1.2972147
2020-05-13 08:45:37 UTC,1.2972147
2020-05-13 08:45:36 UTC,1.2972147
2020-05-13 08:45:35 UTC,1.2972147
2020-05-13 08:45:34 UTC,1.2972147
2020-05-13 08:45:33 UTC,1.2972147
2020-05-13 08:45:15 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:14 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:13 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:12 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:11 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:10 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:09 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:08 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:07 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:06 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:05 UTC,0.76306754
2020-05-13 08:45:04 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:45:03 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:45:02 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:45:01 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:44:42 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:41 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:40 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:39 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:38 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:37 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:36 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:35 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:34 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:33 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:32 UTC,1.5642884
2020-05-13 08:44:31 UTC,1.5642884
2020-05-13 08:44:30 UTC,1.5642884
2020-05-13 08:44:19 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:18 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:17 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:16 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:15 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:14 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:13 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:12 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:11 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:44:10 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:44:09 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:44:08 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:43:53 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:52 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:51 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:50 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:49 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:48 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:47 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:46 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:45 UTC,0.5723007
2020-05-13 08:43:44 UTC,1.5642884
2020-05-13 08:43:43 UTC,1.5642884
2020-05-13 08:43:42 UTC,1.5642884
2020-05-13 08:43:25 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:43:24 UTC,1.4879817
2020-05-13 08:43:08 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:43:07 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:43:06 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:42:50 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:42:49 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:42:48 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:42:47 UTC,1.2590615
2020-05-13 08:42:34 UTC,0.53414726
2020-05-13 08:42:33 UTC,0.53414726
2020-05-13 08:42:32 UTC,0.53414726
```

Unfortunately I didn't find any information how to get min(time) and max(time) for timestamps where Sensor is greater than 1 and aggravate the timestamps to operating hours (duration). I think i need to use minif and maxif in any way.

Could you please help me or give me a little tip?

Best regards,
scotti

Comment: what is expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a query to achieve what you aim. In order to do so, I used the [MAX()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#max) and [MIN()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#min) builtin functions to get the maximum and minimum value of the time stamp for an specific Sensor. Both functions can be used with any datatype apart from `ARRAY STRUCT`. In addition to that, [TIMESTAMP_DIFF()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff) was also used to retrieve the difference between the two timestamps.

I must point that I uploaded the data you provided in the question in a table so I could replicate the case. Below is the query for StandardSQL:

```
SELECT Sensor, MAX(timestamp) AS max_ts , 
MIN(timestamp) AS min_ts, 
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp), SECOND) AS duration_ 
FROM `project_id.dataset.table` 
WHERE Sensor > 1
GROUP BY Sensor
```

And the output,

```
Row Sensor    max_ts                  min_ts                  duration_seconds
1   1.2972147 2020-05-13 08:45:38 UTC 2020-05-13 08:45:33 UTC 5
2   1.4879817 2020-05-13 08:46:22 UTC 2020-05-13 08:43:24 UTC 178
3   1.2590615 2020-05-13 08:43:08 UTC 2020-05-13 08:42:47 UTC 21
4   1.5642884 2020-05-13 08:44:32 UTC 2020-05-13 08:43:42 UTC 50
```

Notice that within `TIMESTAMP_DIFF()` a ***date part*** has to be specified, in this case I selected SECONDS. Although, there are other available date parts, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_diff).